# Regex match digits between two strings not working in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which is working fine in regex101 but not in javascript/jquery, I think because of the `?<=` expression. If I omit this part, it works, but replaces the preceding string as well. I want to replace only the digits in the URL, or in other words all digits between "foo/" and "/bar"

My code:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.domain.com/foo/1234/bar/">Some anchor text</a>
<button>Click</button>

$("button").click(function() {
  $('#link').attr('href', function(index, myhref) {
    return myhref.replace(/(?<=foo\/)(\d+)(?=\/bar)/,'newnumber');
   });
});
```

How do I have to modify my regex so that it replaces the digits?

Comment: You are correct. Look-behinds aren't supported in JavaScript.

Comment: `myhref.replace(/(foo\/)(\d+)(\/bar)/, '$1newnumber$3')`

Comment: @noisypixy Comments are not the place to put answers.

Comment: that rx won't work with `.replace()` (w/o output placeholders), but it could be used with `"".search()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support positive or negative lookbehind. But, you might want to try to capture its group and use them as you're replacing the string.

**E.g**

```
var str = 'http://www.domain.com/foo/1234/bar/';
var myvar = 'newnumber';
var newStr = str.replace(/(foo\/)(\d+)(\/bar)/i, '$1' + myvar + '$3');
// Returns "http://www.domain.com/foo/newnumber/bar/"
```

- `(foo\/)` is the first group, matching `foo/`
- `(\d+)` is the second group, matching any digits number for one or more.
- `(\/bar)` is the third group, matching `/bar`
- `'$1'+ myvar +'$3'` returns a concat of `first group` + `myvar` + `third group`

Comment: That works if I replace it with a string but how would I do it if newnumber is a variable? E.g. (.... , $1 + newnumber + $2) is not working.

Comment: @dandavis That is not lookbehind.

Comment: you can use lookarounds in modes other than match/replace, like exec and search...

Comment: @dandavis It's very well established that look-behinds don't exist in JavaScipt's regex engine. Look it up, or give examples to prove your point.

Comment: @4castle: using the 2nd example from https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html, `"the hound in the picture is not a greyhound".search(/(?<=grey)hound/)` hits "hound" preceded by "grey" and returns 38 like the example. what am i misunderstanding?

Comment: @dandavis That's not JavaScript, that's Racket: a totally different programming language.

Comment: @4castle: ok, so can we say that "Racket" has "look-behinds"? and given that, can we agree that the JS code i posted produces the same output as "Racket"'s "look-behind" example? and given that, how then can it follow that JS does not have "look-behinds"? I'm not a RegExp guru, but the code seems to work...

Comment: @dandavis Because your code won't run in JS. Try it. This isn't the place to discuss this.

Comment: @4castle: you asked for a proof, i think i've provided one. i assure you that `"the hound in the picture is not a greyhound".search(/(?<=grey)hound/)` is JS, and i belive it's an example of lookbehinds, if i'm not mistaken, which is possible (no RX expert here). used the Racket example specifically because it was a non-js example of what "lookbehind" is supposed to accomplish.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112732/discussion-between-4castle-and-dandavis).

Comment: ok, ok, it works in V8 but not firefox, let's call it a draw.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it's because look-behinds aren't supported in JavaScript. Instead you could use an output string that includes the prefix and suffix:

```
return myhref.replace(/foo\/\d+\/bar/,'foo/newnumber/bar');
```

If `newnumber` is a variable, use concatenation:

```
return myhref.replace(/foo\/\d+\/bar/,'foo/' + newnumber + '/bar');
```

Comment: I made an edit to address if `newnumber` was a variable. The same solution applies for @choz

Comment: Thanks your answer helped me I got it working combining your edited answer with @choz original answer!

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
myhref.replace(new RegExp("\/[0-9]*\/", "g"), "/newnumber/")
```

EDIT: if you want to replace the number by a "newnumber" only if it is between **foo** and **bar** then you should add those at RegExp as well as follows. The code above is going to replace the number **without** verifying it.

```
myhref.replace(new RegExp("foo\/[0-9]*\/bar", "g"), "foo/newnumber/bar")
```

Comment: That ignores the prefix and suffix which are required for the match.

Comment: @4castle are you saying that my answer does not work ? I tested it and I cannot understand why it does not work. the delimiter is / before and after the number.

Comment: The delimiters aren't just a `/`. It's specifically `foo/` and `/bar`. `test/123/test` should not match.

Comment: @4castle okay, you're 100% right. I did not read the part "in other words all digits between "foo/" and "/bar""

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/` to match digits in string, `.replace()` matched digits with `newnumber`

```
var str = "http://www.domain.com/foo/1234/bar/";
var newnumber = 5678;
var n = str.match(/\d+/)[0];
str = str.replace(n, newnumber);
```